# "Out of bounds"-error when using PyPlot and ginput

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to interactively get points from an image by clicking on it. For this I am using the pyplot package offered by matplotlib with Python2.7.

I am doing it in the following way:

```
fig = plt.figure()
self.ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
self.ax.imshow(self.image, cmap='gray')
self.ax.axis('image')
self.original_points = plt.ginput(self.clicks, mouse_stop = 3, mouse_pop = 2)
self.image[self.original_points[0]]
```

However gives me the following error:

```
IndexError: index 382 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 362
```

It seems like the x and y coordinates are reversed. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `ginput` returns the `(x,y)` coordinate of the clicked point. So you need to reverse the order.

Also note that you will get floating point coordinates, so before using them for indexing your image, you should make sure to change the type to `int`.

Comment: Thank you. When do I need to reverse the coordinates? Is it only necessary when I'm using them to index an array? And what is the reason for them being reversed?

Comment: Numpy arrays are ordered as (row, column, ...) because that is how you usually index matrices in maths. Since `ginput` gives the point clicked in a graph, which you usually think of as x-y and not y-x, then I suppose giving the point as (x,y) is what most people would expect. You would obviously have to reorder the coordinates in such a way that it makes sense for your data :)

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I'm doing some Computer Vision and this resulted in some funky results!

So it's due to the way that the axis of images are viewed differently than that of arrays. `ginput` returns (x,y). For plotting: (x,y). For indexing: (y,x)

Comment: Yes. It is quite common in Computer Vision to regard images as matrices, and then the indexing in the image is usually in the order of (row, column, channel).